# Sequelize - fetch from a table that is not defined (but is created from association)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I'm working on a new project and I'm facing this problem;

So let's say in sequelize the tables `User` and `Project` are defined.

In the DB, there is a third table `ProjectsUsers`, and I need to fetch from that.

This table only has columns like userId, createdAt, updatedAt, which are the default ones, so the table isn't defined in the model.

Should I define it (as an empty table) in the model (not sure if it would break things or not, but seems unlikely to work).

How can I query that table?

Answer (score 0):

Just define a table with right association and you will be able to query on it.

For example:

```
var UserModel = sequelize.define('user', {},{});
var ProjectModel = sequelize.define('project', {}, {});
var ProjectsUsersModel = sequelize.define( 'ProjectsUsers', {}, {} );

UserModel.hasMany( ProjectModel );
ProjectModel.hasMany( UserModel )
CourseTopics.belongsTo( topicModel ).belongsTo( ProjectModel );

ProjectsUsersModel.findAll({include:[UserModel, ProjectModel]})
.success(function(projectsUsers) {
 });
```